# What are the process and considerations to get off-grid using solar panels?

Tags: solar-panels

Can anyone tell me what type of solar panel is considered the best for generation of power and price?

I already have 3.5 KW of Solar PV on my roof which I benefit from the UK Feed In Tariff.

Now I want to explore if adding the right and most affordable type of panels hooked up to a battery can get me off grid.

Comment: Found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-nvBuCrZOI

Comment: Would use google for UK off grid solar power and see what it says.  Solar panels are only a small part of the information people needs to consider when setting up a system.  Would check non solar power business information sites first.

Comment: "Most affordable panels" and "off-grid" (when you have grid available already, and grid-tie available) are fundamental opposites. Panel costs are a TINY FRACTION of off-grid SYSTEM COSTS, unless you are happy to have no power when the sun does not shine and the wind does not blow, and only as much power as they happen to produce when they do. Storage is a VAST money pit - using the grid instead is a major cost win.

Comment: As it stands this is a shopping question.

Comment: If you are finding two panels which generate the same kW/h but one is double the price of the other then it would be fair to ask why is the price so wildly different.

Comment: If not shopping, it's too broad. Discussions about type would need to be in the context of a specific application.

Comment: This got closed because it's unclear whether you are trying to get us to help you pick a make/model of panel... or trying to understand the technology of a battery/inverter system that can carry your house through outages.  *I don't think you quite know yourself :)* and that's fine, but we can only help with clear questions of reasonably narrow focus.  I will say you are awfully "shopping-focused" considering how much you need to learn about the underlying tech.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to start by evaluating your load:

1. daily load including maximum demand
2. weekly load
3. monthly and annual load.

Then you can work out how many panels you need, as winter sunshine is different to summer.

The next consideration is storage so you have power at night and also stored power to cover the series of cloudy days... How will you deal with low insolation for 3 weeks or 5 weeks?

Choosing a panel manufacturer is a **long** way down the list, evaluate your needs first and think about the devices you use, the ones you leave on when you should not etc etc

The 2.7kW peak I fitted to the house in Switzerland more than covers the annual energy needs but it is grid-tied so during the winter it imports and summer it exports.

Comment: thank you, I should add that I'm planning on installing wind turbines too...home made.

Comment: @SPlatten still, no matter if you go with solar, wind, hydro or biomass, you need to evaluate your energy use first.

Comment: And "evaluate your energy use" means identifying and getting rid of inefficient appliances.  It's cheaper to spend £500 replacing your refrigerator than £1500 fitting enough panels to power your old fridge.